# Configurar multiplos logs no Apache

Tags: apache, log

Estou trabalhando em uma rede interna onde estão rodando 3 aplicações no servidor Apache. Gostaria de poder analisar o log gerado pelo Apache separadamente por cada aplicação mas, como não tenho acesso ao servidor DNS as configurações do Apache encontram-se no arquivo padrão: **000-default.conf**.

Neste caso seria possível especificar neste arquivo onde salvar este log separadamente? Algo como:

```
<Directory /home/user/www/app1/>
     ...
     ErrorLog /home/user/www/app1/storage/
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user/www/app2/>
     ...
     ErrorLog /home/user/www/app2/storage/
</Directory>
```

Comment: sim.. é conforme postou... qual a dificuldade?

Comment: É exatamente desse jeito? Posso colocar as a diretiva ErrorLog dentro de Directory? Não encontrei nada parecido na documentação do Apache, então fiquei na dúvida.

Comment: Você nem tentou?

Comment: tenta ué........